# Cannot send data from RaspberryPi to Arduino using UART

Tags: raspbian, arduino, uart

I want to send data from RaspberryPi to Arduino UNO using UART. 
I tried sending my data 10 times to Arduino but it received it once.
It reads as follows.

```
Connected to PC
pi: ÿpi: ÿpi: ÿ
```

1) I modified two files:

**boot/cmdline.txt:** to

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,9600 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,9600 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
```

**etc/inittab:** to

```
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 9600 vt10
```

2) I connected Arduino to my PC using USB UART and to Rpi

pin 10(Arduino) to pin 8(Raspberry)

pin 11(Arduino) to pin 10(Raspberry)

This is my Arduino code to receive data over UART:

```
/*
 Connects Arduino to Raspberry Pi
 Arduino: SoftSerial
 Raspberry Pi: GPIO UART 
 Just connect pin 10(Arduino) to pin 8(Raspberry)  
              pin 11(Arduino) to pin 10(Raspberry)  
 */
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to PC");
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  // If data is available on Raspberry Pi, print it to PC
  if (mySerial.available()){
      Serial.print("pi: ");
      Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  }
}
```

3) On Raspberry i use python:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO Library 
import time ## Import 'time' library.  Allows us to use 'sleep' 
import sys, getopt
import serial

print('Dang thuc thi')

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600,timeout=1)
#port.write("\r\n" + args[0])
port.open();
a = 0;
while a<10:
    port.write('data ' + str(a))
    a=a+1
    print('times: '+ str(a))
    time.sleep(1.2)
port.close()
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to disable serial console on Rpi which is on by default. If you're running a new version of raspbian. Run `sudo raspi-config`, go to `8. Advanced options`, Go to `Serial` and select `disable`. It will disable your serial console. You will have to reboot to make it effective.

If you don't want to make changes using `raspi-config` way.

1. Like you said, change your `/boot/cmdline.txt` to look like follow. Ie, remove any reference to `/dev/ttyAMA0`.

   ```
   dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
   ```
2. Open /etc/inittab and comment out (insert `#` at the very beginning) following line to make it look like as below.

   `#T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100`

Second point, Rpi is a 3v3 device while Arduino is 5v device. So while connecting both of them, you must use a level shifter to convert 5v logic to 3v3 logic else it can damage your RPi.

Here is a connection circuit for your reference.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I also send data from Raspberry PI to Arduion.  (Is it possiple when only connect RX (Arduino) with TX (Raspberry PI) ?)

Comment: @user3326893 Yes, ideally it is. In that case, it would be simplex communication ie, one way.

Comment: @user3326893 Make sure that you have disabled serial console as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: i remember I tried your way. but it doesn't work. I will try again!

Comment: I just try! when i connect RX (Arduino) with TX (Raspberry PI) . On arduino display 

`ÿpi: ÿpi: ÿpi: ÿpi: ÿpi: ÿpi: ÿpi:pi: ÿpi: ÿpi: ÿpi: ÿpi: Çpi: ÿpi: ópi: ÿpi: ƒpi: pi: ÿpi: Ã` 
very long! always receive data!

Comment: What should i do now? :(
. My Rpi is damaged? When i type this command to check Pins
`stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0` 
**Result:** 
`speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel`

Comment: @user3326893 You can test if UART is damaged or not by connecting link between Rpi pin 8 and 10. and then run your python with slight modification. Before port.close() you should add : print port.read(port.inWaiting()). See if it prints 1 to 10 as per you're sending.

Comment: ok! it's not demaged! :) 
`data 0data 1data 2data 3data 4data 5data 6data 7data 8data 9`.     
I cannot understand why have too long data display when i connect arduino with Rpi? Could you tell me? ^^ Thank you!

Comment: @user3326893 Just to make sure, have you connected Rpi ground (pin 6) with Arduino ground ? Like depicted in that circuit ? It is necessary to have common ground.

Comment: Thank you very much about your help! ^^
My Rpi is ok. 

I have changed to [link] RF UART device (http://www.sunrom.com/p/rf-serial-data-link-uart-433-mhz-1km) instead of Arduino. 
                  it's ok!

Comment: @user3326893 I don't have an Uno but I tested it over my Arduino Duemilanove. I ran the exact same program except this line. I change 10,11 to `SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);` suit my board. From the diagram above I can tell that it is same for uno ? Just confirm it once. For me, it's working with this modification. Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't know why. It doesn't work with Arduino UNO when i connect RX (Arduino) with TX (Raspberry PI). Data received: `ÿÃÃÃÿÿûÿÿÿÿÿÿÿûÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ`

Comment: @user3326893 I'm out of ideas now why it is not working on your setup. Did you try connecting rx and tx of arduino to see if it's working with suitable program ? We made sure that Rpi's serial is working for sure. That might be worth checking.

Comment: Now! I use RF UART module  instead of using arduino. (it's better and more convinience) ^^

Tomorow, when i have more devices. 
I will try connecting arduino with Rpi to check clearly! :)